Determining the Nature of a Function Given a Specific Integral Condition
Consider the integral condition:
$$\int_{-a}^{c} f(x) \, \Bbb dx = \int_{c}^{a} f(x) \, \Bbb dx $$
for every $ -a < c < a $. How can we determine the nature of the function $ f(x) $ in the interval $(-a, a)$?
Details:
This equation implies that the area under $f(x)$ from $-a$ to $c$ is equal to the area from $c$ to $a$. Intuitively, this suggests a certain symmetry about any point $c$ in the interval.
What kind of functions might satisfy this condition?
Thank you for your help!

$$\int_{-a}^{a} f(x) \, dx   = \int_{-a}^{c} f(x) \, dx + \int_{c}^{a} f(x) \, dx = 2\int_{-a}^{c} f(x) \, dx $$ and so $$\int_{-a}^{c} f(x) \, dx =\text{const}$$
and further $$f(c)= \frac d {dc} \int_{-a}^{c} f(x) \, dx  = 0$$ for $c \in (-a,a)$.
